# Why is the object returned from the function undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a function that essentially looks like this (slightly simplified):

```
function drawCircle(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
        if (status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            var circ = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center:results[0].geometry.location,
                    clickable:false,
                    fillColor:colors[count],
                    fillOpacity:.3, 
                    map:map,
                    radius:200,
                    strokeOpacity:.3,
                    zIndex:2 
                });

            ...

            return circ;
        }
        else{
            //geocode unsuccessful, alert user
            alert("Could not find location");
        }
    });
}
```

It draws a radius circle on a google map around the address passed in to the function. It then returns the circle object.

However, when I try to use the result of this function, it always returns undefined, even if the circle was successfully drawn.

```
var myCircle = drawCircle("someAddress");
```

When I step through this code (with Firebug), the `circ` variable *is* defined and contains a google maps circle object at the time of the return statement. However, on the other side, it gets assigned to myCircle as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, the result isn't available until the callback function runs, by that time the function itself has already returned.

Comment: @geocodezip - not sure if I understand; I'm returning circ from within the callback function, where it is actually defined.

Comment: The outer function has finished executing by the time that return is hit

Comment: @geocodezip - how can I solve this? Is there any way to force the geocode call to be synchronous?

Comment: @froadie: That's the wrong approach. Instead, you want to delay the rest of your outer function until geocoder has finished (asynchronously).

Comment: The correct approach is to use the data returned by the geocoder when the callback runs (that is what it is for), if you need access to it in the global scope later, store a reference to it in a global variable.

Comment: [example that puts a circle on the result of a geocoder search](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_radiusSearch.html) (does a radius search also, but doesn't sound like you need that part)